# Knowledge Base solution for Magento?

Tags: magento, plugin

I'm looking for a knowledge base solution for magento.  Does anybody know of any available?

Comment: http://alanstorm.com/category/magento for programming tutorials.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki for general stuff.

Comment: Do you search for an extension for magento which will provide the functionality of a knowledge base?

Comment: There is a proposal for Magento Q&A site on Stack Exchange you can [join here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25439/magento?referrer=3aQY0b01ZQxK1tHpMPMEAg2).

Comment: You need to make your question clearer.  Are you talking about a helpdesk/knowledge base system that integrates with Magento?

Answer (score 0):

http://alanstorm.com/category/magento for programming tutorials.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki for general stuff.